# Android Application crash with Application has Stopped ,but no error code shown

Tags: android

My Android app compiles fine but crashed with the message Application has stopped. What is the problem with my code?

```
package com.example.set;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Button btn1;
private Button btn2;
private Button btn3;
private Button btn4;
private Button btn5;

Intent Intentlist;
int intentcode1;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn5);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


        public void onClick(View v) {

               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.btn1:
            Intent myAplikasi1 = new Intent(this, Main.class);
            startActivity(myAplikasi1);
            finish();
            break;

            case R.id.btn2:
            Intent myAplikasi2 = new Intent(this, Credit.class);
            startActivity(myAplikasi2);
            finish();
            break;


            case R.id.btn5:
                Intent myAplikasi5 = new Intent(this, Galeri.class);
                startActivity(myAplikasi5);
                finish();
                break;



            case R.id.btn4:
            Intent myAplikasi3 = new Intent(this, sejarah.class);
            startActivity(myAplikasi3);
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
            break;



            case R.id.btn3:
                keluar(); 
                finish();
                return;



            }
      }

        public void keluar(){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Apakah Anda Benar-Benar ingin keluar?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Ya",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                              MainActivity.this.finish();

                        }
                  })
            .setNegativeButton("Tidak",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()   {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                              dialog.cancel();
                        }
                  }).show();
            }



public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
     return true;
     }

    }
```

this my layout

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/asss"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn2"
android:layout_width="280dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_x="27dp"
android:layout_y="340dp"
android:text="credit" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn3"
android:layout_width="273dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_x="26dp"
android:layout_y="439dp"
android:text="exit" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn4"
android:layout_width="271dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_x="33dp"
android:layout_y="392dp"
android:text="Sejarah" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button5"
android:layout_width="280dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_x="27dp"
android:layout_y="289dp"
android:hint="Galeri"
android:text="Galeri" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn1"
android:layout_width="274dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_x="29dp"
android:layout_y="240dp"
android:hint="Mulai"
android:text="Mulai" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

this all happen after i use clean project all error disappear but whent start this apk says stopped work

logcat

```
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657): java.lang.RuntimeException:    Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.set/com.example.set.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at com.example.set.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at      android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-09 08:15:07.398: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Did it crash when you tried to press btn2 ? or for all buttons? And in layout you have Button5 as id but in switch case you are using btn5.

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu this app event cant be start that crash shown when i just open apk